# Failure condition for free space check in Ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts, cisco-ios

Working on writing a playbook to update the fleet of Cisco switches we run, but I am having trouble with a specific line I am using to verify there is sufficient free space on the stack.

Cut the relevant sections of the playbook here.

```
---
- hosts: Cisco2960
  vars:

    - firmware_image_size: "41555"
  tasks:
    - name: Checking for available free space...
      fail:
        msg: "Insufficient free space on the stack. Please check the flash: directory."
      when: ansible_net_filesystems_info[flash:]['spacefree_kb'] > firmware_image_size
```

The idea was that I would check the data from the ios_facts module, (run earlier in the playbook) and compare the value pulled to the explicitly defined variable.

After reviewing the documentation, it looks like the data type is exported from ansible_net_filesystems_info is in a dictionary. Would the problem be that I am comparing two not-like data types?

Comment: What is the problem you're having: is the conditional not behaving as you expect, or are you getting an error of some sort?

Comment: What a great idea to use the colon in the name of a directory!

Answer (score 2):

Q: ***"Am I comparing two not-like data types?"***

A: Yes. Remove the quotes from *firmware_image_size*

```yaml
firmware_image_size: 41555
```

and fix the [bracket notation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#referencing-key-value-dictionary-variables)

```yaml
ansible_net_filesystems_info['flash:']['spacefree_kb']
```

Details: The [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/cisco/ios/ios_facts_module.html#return-ansible_net_filesystems_info) is only telling us that *ansible_net_filesystems_info* is a dictionary. From the [code](https://github.com/ansible-collections/cisco.ios/blob/main/plugins/module_utils/network/ios/facts/legacy/base.py#L169) we can see that the attribute *spacetotal_kb* is an integer. The problem is that you declare *firmware_image_size* as a string

```yaml
firmware_image_size: "41555"
```

If you compare an integer (fixed [bracket notation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#referencing-key-value-dictionary-variables)) to a string

```yaml
when: ansible_net_filesystems_info['flash:']['spacefree_kb'] > firmware_image_size
```

you'll see the condition failed:

> fatal: ... ''>'' not supported between instances of ''int'' and ''AnsibleUnicode''

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    ansible_net_filesystems_info:
      'flash:':
        spacefree_kb: 50000
    firmware_image_size: 41555
  tasks:
    - assert:
        that:
          - ansible_net_filesystems_info['flash:'].spacefree_kb > firmware_image_size
        fail_msg: Insufficient free space on the stack. Please check the 'flash:' directory.
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
  msg: All assertions passed
```